# Convert salary value given in string to numeric while ensuring all values are in same unit in a database using python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I have a dataset which has values of players given as a string. Values of few players are in millions while others are in thousands. I want to convert all these into float from string with values in millions.

Tried to iterate through the rows while checking if 'K' representing thousand is there or not and if it is then divide it by 1000 to convert it into million.

```
for x in dataset['Value'].tolist():
    s = pd.Series(x)
    if 'K' in s: 
        x = x.map(lambda x: str(x)[:-1])
        x = x.map(lambda x: str(x)[1:])
        x = pd.to_numeric(x)
        x = x/1000
    else:
        x = x.map(lambda x: str(x)[:-1])
        x = x.map(lambda x: str(x)[1:])
        x = pd.to_numeric(x)
```

'str' object has no attribute 'map'.

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```py
def to_millions(s):
  if s.endswith('K'):
    return float(s.rstrip('K')) / 1000.0
  else:
    return float(s)
```

Note: `float` is a poor representation of monetary values, unless all you do is rough estimates. Real finance applications use `Decimal`.

Re the use of `.map`: I have no idea either what the code tried to achieve.